# No Exists method so I want to use AsQueryable for defensive programming

Tags: c#, linq, defensive-programming, asqueryable

I am writing some code which queries the Visual Studio object model.

I see that there is no `Exists` method on the `Projects` collection object but I do like defensive programming and not relying on try catch blocks.  So I see there is `AsQueryable()` on the `Projects` object and I was wondering if this could help.

I can see [here](http://tutlane.com/tutorial/linq/linq-asqueryable-method) the sort of code I want to write,

```
IQueryable<Student> query = 
    objStudent.AsQueryable().Where(student => student.Name.Contains("Alavala"));
```

but for me it would be something like

```
IQueryable<EnvDTE.Project> query = 
    sol.Projects.AsQueryable().Where(proj => proj.Name=project);
```

but this does not compile giving the error message

> 'IQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'IQueryable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Is it just a missing reference?  Here is the minimal recreatable code ...

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace AsQueryableConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            /* ensure the solution is running in a separate instance of Visual Studio 2017 */
            string solution = @"C:\Users\Simon\source\repos\WebApplication1\WebApplication1.sln";


            string project = "WebApplication1";
            //string projectItem = "WebForm1.aspx";

            object objSol = Marshal.BindToMoniker(solution); /* should bind if running */
            EnvDTE.Solution sol = (EnvDTE.Solution)objSol;     /* does a cast */

            /* next line does not compile with error message 
                Error   CS1061  
                'IQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'IQueryable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) AsQueryableConsoleApp   
             */
            IQueryable<EnvDTE.Project> query = sol.Projects.AsQueryable().Where(proj => proj.Name = project);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is following directive added: `using System.Linq;`?

Comment: Does it work, after adding?

Comment: What happens when you use `var` instead of `IQueryable<EnvDTE.Project>`?

Comment: IQueryable definetley has a `.Where()` so you are doing something wrong here.

Comment: What is an `EnvDTE.Solution` ? and what is the `.Projects` there?

Comment: But is it a DbContext?

Comment: So, what are they then? Do cocument your case better, and maybe write a [mcve]

Comment: @HenkHolterman, this is code related to VS extensibility.

Comment: @SMeaden, you should not even need IQueryable. IEnumerable should do just fine to use the Linq to Objects 'Where' method.

Comment: @jeroenh : happy to use IEnumerable if can be used defensively, there is no Exists method, no ToList method either.

Comment: Have updated code but you need a separate instance of VS2017 running and we have to change the solution file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EnvDTE.Projects is not a 'generic collection', it only implements the non-generic IEnumerable (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.projects?view=visualstudiosdk-2017)

You need to convert to a generic `IEnumerable<T>` first, using `Cast` or `OfType`:

```
   var query = sol.Projects.OfType<EnvDTE.Project>().Where(proj => proj.Name == project);
```

Comment: As I said earlier, no need to go through `IQueryable` in this case, it will only make it (probably not noticably, but still) slower